# Send remainders via email based on DueDates in tasklist

Tags: sharepoint-online, task-list, sharepoint-list

I have a SharePoint task list with DueDate field. Users would like to get notified via email 2 days before the DueDate and on DueDate. what would be an easy approach to send this email.

Workflows run on current items and items changed but not on all the items in the list.

any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run the workflow on all items you can create a site workflow to make it run daily.

The site workflow gets the records using `HTTP Web Call` and loop through all items send an email. Below is a sample.

[image]

1. It requires running 2 steps for 2 notifications
2. Step 1: to get the records which match all items Today() = due date - 2
3. Step 2: to get the records which match all items Today() = due date